# Why do exports include only hard products?

Tags: balance-of-trade

- Looking at country lists by exports.
- Diving into exports always shows things like gas turbines, computer hardware, petrolium -- all physical things.
- None show things like exporting services: financial services, engineering consulting, licensing software. I would imagine that would be a considerable component in countries like UK. In some countries medical tourism might bring considerable revenue.
- If traditional export metric is for hard products only is there a metric that encompasses service export as well? And is there any data on account balance (export - inport) of countries with services included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fairly nice one from [OECD](https://data.oecd.org/trade/trade-in-goods-and-services.htm#indicator-chart). It includes combined trade in goods and services as a percentage of GDP. It is also possible to drill into goods only (which seems most commonly presented in the public domain) or services only data.

Comment: So the answer to your question is that exports do include services and the question was based on a mistaken assumption?

Comment: It seems it is a fuzzy definition and normally what is meant by exports only includes hard products which is misleading.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger Every definition of total exports I have seen includes services. As a result, this answer does seem to answer the question, and it would be best to mark the question as answered.